# Unexpected Header View in UITableView's section using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableheader

[image]

It is easy to see, that the lightblue is a **`UITableViewHeaderFooterView`**, and the white one is **`UITableViewCell`**. I use `NSFetchedResultsController` to load sections and groups from CoreData. Every blue header is a new section.

**SOMETIMES (not always)** there is a **header view** instead of a **table view cell**. Why?

In `viewDidLoad` i register header View:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PBOUserWorkDayHeaderView", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: PBOUserWorkDayHeaderViewIdentifier)
```

What is more interesting, when I Debug View Hierarchy you can see, that there is my custom cell, just covered by header. Why?

[image]

**Is it iOS bug? What do you think?** Sth wrong with rendering or with my way of thinking?

Comment: Oh, that's weird... Can you post a repo with just the TableViewController code and static datas? Check if you don't have identical ids on IB, for cells and headers.

Comment: You can try a reloadData() on the tableView, but it's not efficient, but it can solve the problem temporarily.

Comment: A more efficient solution should be to use `view.setNeedsDisplay()`. It's just repaint your UITableView, and not recreate alle the TableView as `reloadData()`does.

Comment: Can you post some code? Did you have implemented `heightForHeaderInSection` ?

Comment: Can you post your implementation of this function?

Comment: Ok, it wasn't what I thought... So without all your tableview implementation it's complicated to guess what is happening. Are you using row height estimation provided with iOS 8? (Did you set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` ?)

Comment: From you're view hierarchy, it's not a row height problem, it's a z-index problem, you can try forcing the z-index of your rows, but it's ugly :s

Comment: Look at this article : http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/nsfetchedresultscontroller-documentation-bug/ it's old but NSFetchedresultsController should still work asynchronously

Comment: Yes very weird issue! So one thing is sure, the problem comes from `NSFetchedResultsController`, if you don't have the same behavior with the  same static data... Did you try using the debugger? Put a breakpoint before the tableview render, and go step by step looking your view hierarchy on each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a problem with headers, I created a custom method to remove unnecessary headers every time when `tableView` ask for `viewForHeaderInSection:.

Assuming that you know how to distinguish the headers from other views (in my case they have a custom class) and that you know that **header views** are **direct subviews** of `tableView` you can remove them in following way:

```
private func removeDoubledHeaders() {
    let subviews = tableView.subviews.reverse()

    var dates = [String]()
    for view in subviews {
        if let header = view as? PBOUserWorkDayHeaderView {
            if let date = header.dateLabel.text {
                if contains(dates, date) {
                    view.removeFromSuperview()
                } else {
                    dates.append(date)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  I can't seem to fix the bug so this work-around is the next best thing!